# How to make PHP results show up blog style

Tags: php, echo

Alright, this might be a little confusing to understand, but I'm going to take my best shot at describing what I want to happen....

I have a while loop that continues over code several thousands of times.. As it does this, I made it print out a line each time the loop increases a value. The echo prints out on the page on a new line each and every time and continues down the page (Which works fine), but I wanted to know if there's a way to make the new echo show up on the topline of the page instead of going down to the bottom of the page (Below the other results). So in short terms, I want to make it so that each no echo in the loop shows up like a blog post (on the top).

Comment: What code do you have so far?  It'll be much easier to answer your question if we can see the code.

Comment: Reverse the data before you start looping over it.

Comment: Thousands of lines of code within a loop sounds like a serious design flaw.

Comment: @Robinv.G. He loops several thousand times, he doesn't have several thousand lines of code in the loop.  Either way though it completely depends on the scenario as to whether it is a good or bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Well you just need to reorder your information, if for example the information is coming from an sql databse you should use an **ORDER BY** statement to get the information in the order in which you want to display it, this will make life much easier.

Comment: He never said he was processing a database.

Comment: Again; Jon here said: "`if *for example* the information is coming from an sql databse`". The actual point he's making here is "`you just need to reorder your information`". The rest is details and just being helpful.

Comment: He never referred to thousands of records of information. He never mentioned a database, or any array. He said he was printing out a value on each pass through a loop. He could be doing math, for all we know.

Comment: @MikeFulton What difference does it make? Then he needs to do his math in reverse order, or, store the results in an array and then reverse the array before echo'ing the results. Or, keep everything as-is and use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11542914/215042) to output the results in reverse order. I don't understand the point you're trying to make. Jon was just contributing examples.

Comment: @MikeFulton My first statement still stands, my second statement was an example of a possible situation, one which in all fairness is pretty likely, if not for this user, then for other users which will come across this question.

Comment: @Jon Taylor -- The point is there isn't necessarily any pre-existing information to reverse. Suggesting that's what he needs to do isn't going to help in that case.

Comment: @Roblll -- you usually cannot do an iterative math calculation in reverse order. If you could, it would make the loop unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: @MikeFulton Either way, all of our answers are correct ways of doing things.  I prefer to give examples that may prompt people to rethink their situation, I knwo that a lot of beginners would not necesserily think theres anything they can do `SQL` side (If this was a sql problem, which to me the "blog style" would suggest).  They may just be asking for the printing and looping because they believe that this is indeed the part that needs correcting.

Comment: By "blog style" he was simply referring to the way blogs normally have the newest entries at the top. However, maybe you're right. I suppose it's reasonable to think he might be something of a beginner, because of the nature of the question. I didn't really worry about that. I was focused on simply providing the shortest possible path to the result I thought he was looking for.

Comment: Fair enough but shortest is not always best.  I know from experience teaching second and final year university students that often the best solutions are the ones they don't event think about, they go for other options which may seem short and simple but actually complicate the code unnecessarily.  I am not saying for definite that he is getting stuff from a database, but "blog style" does indeed suggest to me that he is performing some sort of similar action, perhaps pulling information from a database, perhaps not.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off [reversing the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) you're iterating. If you're not iterating an array but some SQL resultset than just add an order clause (`order by foo` or `order by foo ASC`, both being **ascending** order or `order by foo DESC` for **descending**) to your query.

If neither is the case, do this:

```
$output = '';
while (something) {
  $output = 'blahblah' . $output;
}
echo $output;
```

Whatever the case may be; "several thousands of times" sounds like a bad plan. Maybe you need [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination)?

Comment: He never said he was processing an array, or a database.

Comment: I also never said that: "`If you're not iterating an array but some SQL resultset... If neither is the case...`". Also I provided a sample that doesn't have anything to do with a database. So I don't understand your comment??

Comment: Sorry, I meant that comment for the other answer. Posted it in wrong place. Thought I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't immediately echo your results. Instead, save them to a string and append the previous results to the new ones.

```
$output = "";
do 
{
    $newresults = doWhatever();
    $output = $newresults . $output;
}
while( $stillWannaLoop == true );
echo $output;
```